# How to point to the expected char array after passing char* into a function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, char

Why I can not change the content the char* points to?
For example:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char *a = NULL; // now a = NULL
    b(a);
    // but now a points to NULL again! Why?
}

void b(char *argv[], char* c) {
    // now a is passed in 
    c = *argv[3];
    // now a actually points to the start of char array pointed to by argv[3]
}
```

From the output, I see the *a is passed to the function. Then inside the function b, it actually pointed to the expected char[ ]. But when returned from b, a became NULL again. Why? And how can a points to expected content after return from b? Thank you!

Comment: This is just massively wrong C, you shouldn't be surprised that it behaves bizarrely. Declare a proper function prototype and it'll fail to compile, just as you'd expect and want it to.

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are trying to do in this example. Please read through the basics of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C passes everything by value, including pointers. Function parameters are similar to local variables that acquire their initial value from the caller. Once you are inside the function, the value of the parameter can be changed freely without influencing the values passed by the caller.

C's way of passing modifiable stuff into a function is passing pointers. If you want to modify a value of some type `T`, you pass a pointer to `T`; if you want to modify a pointer to `T`, you must pass a pointer to a pointer to `T`, and so on. In other words, *the level of indirection* must be higher by one than that of the value being changed.

How does this apply to your case? Your function `b` needs to modify a pointer to `char`, hence it needs to take a pointer to a pointer to a char, like this:

```
void b(char *argv[], char **ppc) {
    ...
}
```

Inside the function you modify the pointer to which `ppc` points by dereferencing `ppc` once:

```
*ppc = argv[3]; // No asterisk here in front of `argv`
```

Of course calling `b` from the `main` needs to take the address of `a`, like this:

```
b(argv, &a);
```